# Tablas relacionadas laravel - datos tipo integer

Tags: laravel

Hola quiero relacionar tres tablas

una tabla persona que tiene un rut

```
      public function up()
      {
       Schema::create('personas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('rut')->unsigned();
        $table->char('dv', 1);
        $table->string('nombre',255);
        $table->string('clave',255);
        $table->string('tipo',255);
        $table->timestamps();
        });
         }
```

Una tabla lider, que tiene un campo rut persona de tipo entero que se relaciona con la tabla persona (rut).
y un campo grupo_id que se relaciona con la tabla grupo a través del id_grupo

```
       public function up()
         { 
       Schema::create('lider', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('rut_persona')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('grupo_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('rut_persona')->references('rut')->on('personas')- 
       >onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('grupo_id')->references('id_grupo')->on('grupo')->onDelete('cascade');
       });
        }
```

esta es la tabla grupo, tambien esta relacionada con una area que es otra tabla, pero el error me lo arroja con estas tres tablas

```
        public function up()
          {
        Schema::create('grupo', function (Blueprint $table) {
      
        $table->integer('id_grupo')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('numero');
        $table->string('direccion', 255);
        $table->string('url_direccion',2000);
        $table->timestamps();
          $table->foreign('id_grupo')->references('id_area')->on('area')->onDelete('cascade');
          });
         }
```

aqui esta el error que me aparece por consola:

```
            SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `back`.`lider` (errno: 150 
            "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `lider` add 
            constraint `lider_rut_persona_foreign` foreign key (`rut_persona`) references 
             `personas` (`rut`) on delete cascade)
```

Luego en otra linea me aparece el siguiente error:

```
             SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `back`.`lider` (errno: 
              150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

elimino la tabla lider, y ejecuto la consulta php artisan migrate y me siguen apareciendo errores, que podria estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Tienes que revisar el orden en el que se ejecutan tus migraciones recuerda que no puedes relacionar una tabla con otra que no se ha creado aun

Comment: Voy a revisar :)

Comment: sigo con el problema, he creado todas las tablas y luego acualice las tablas con el comando php artisan migrate:refresh  agregando las llaves foreanas, pero ahora me dice que llave foreana esta incorrecta